# Protege Ontology Help Sub class, Sibling Class

Tags: ontology, protege

quick question ive got a couple of sibling classes which include sub classes now what i want to do is connect a sub classes to two diffrent sibling classes, is this possible? also i want it to show in the owlviz.

example

sibling class:
rules
goals

sub class:
collect

so i want sub class collect to feature or be connected in both of the sibling classes. as the software does let me type the same name in each sibling class.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question. You can just assert the fact that collect is a subclass of both rules and goals straight from the Protege User Interface.

1. Make sure all of your classes are present in your isA hierarchy
2. Select the class collect
3. In Protege 4, click on the little "+" icon next to the "Superclasses" section in the Class Description Window
4. Assert "rules" as a superclass
5. Repeat and assert "goals" as a superclass.

Now "collect is a subclass of both "rules" and "goals".

AS an aside, it is not normally considered good practice to have multiple asserted inheritance in ontologies. For large ontologies, this can become a maintenance nightmare. If all you need is a small practical solution to a problem, then ok.

The visualisation of your ontology can also be done Protege - you need Graphviz installed first and point Protege to the location of the graphviz executable on your system.

Hope this helps!